# Why does document.getElementsByClassname() kill tizen web app?

Tags: javascript, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I have some html similar to this, using TAU:

```
<div class="ui-page" id="initialize-page">
    <div class="ui-header">
        <h2 class="ui-title">Page1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-footer ui-bottom-button">
        <button class="ui-btn startBtn" id="Test1Btn">Continue</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-page" id="debug-page">
    <div class="ui-header">
        <h2 class="ui-title">Page2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-content">
        <article>
            <section class="contents" id="setup">
                <div>
                    <button class="ui-btn startBtn" id="start">Start</button>
                    <button class="ui-btn" id="pause">Pause</button>
                    <textarea disabled id="infobox"></textarea>
                </div>
            </section>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I try to select the two buttons with `startBtn` in their class attribute with JavaScript like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var startBtnList = document.getElementsByClassName('startBtn');
}
```

But everytime I start the debugging on the Gear S3 the Application hangs up at this line, as if it was an endless loop. I cannot see why. Does someone have a clue?

Comment: what happens with window.addEventListener ?

Comment: you mean when I replace window.onload = function with window.addEventListener('onload', function(){...}) ?

Comment: What is your goal ? Do you want to make a event listener for the Start button ?

Comment: I am trying to add the same event listener to both buttons which are specified with the `starBtn` class, no matter of how much buttons of this class there might be

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName() returns array. Use getElementsByClassName('startBtn')[0] and getElementsByClassName('startBtn')[1] seperately.

Comment: and wheres your answer?

Comment: Elements should be plural in both of your cases, don't want someone copying and pasting and not catching that. JS is pretty intuitive where getElementById is singular and returns 1 element, and getElementsByClassname is plural and returns multiple

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the note :)

Comment: But why can't I assign the array returned by getElementsByClassName('startBtn') to the var startBtnList?

Comment: What did you try to do after assigning it?

Comment: despite the fact that the application did never went past this line, I intended to use it like an array and change the button's disabled state and add ChangeListeners to them